# List down uri of all blobs in azure container

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I know that we can use the below to get the list of blobs in a Azure storage container:

```
var list = fileContainer.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

Then how bout getting the list of uri of all the blobs?

I tried the below but failed cos got error:

```
List<string> blobNamesUri = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name.Uri.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem locates at `b.Name.Uri.ToString()`, Uri is the property of CloudBlockBlob instead of Name. You should remove Name like this `b.Uri.ToString()`. You probably are influenced by your parameter name `blobNamesUri`.

Comment: I tried your method but still with error. The error is with '.Select' function.

Comment: @Coolguy Any concrete message do you get? This method causes no error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I write a demo for you, you can use it directly.

Here you go:

```
    public static List<V> listAllBlobs<T,V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> expression, string containerName)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxx;AccountKey=xxxxx;BlobEndpoint=https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://xxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://xxxxxx.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://xxxxx.file.core.windows.net/;");

        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        var list = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);

        List<V> data = list.OfType<T>().Select(expression.Compile()).ToList();
        return data;
    }
```

Usage and Screenshot:

[image]